# Как сделать поиск фрагмента одного аудиофайла в другом аудиофайле?

Tags: php, python, аудио, ffmpeg

Есть два wav файла, каким способом возможно определить содержится ли один файл в другом?

Желательно библиотека на python или php или какой-нибудь сервис с API.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: разбить звук на дельты взять площадь под кривой, и сравнивать =)